# Laravel find or fail Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new on laravel and trying to understand this framework.

I have DB table called 'matches' and db table called 'logs'.

This 2 tables have custom ID called 'match_id'.

I'm trying to take out logs to custom match. Example:

```
$match->chatMessage = DB::table('logs')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->first()->message;
```

Works fine. But how to make it if 'matches' dont found any rows with custom match_id ?

Now i'm getting error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Thanks for answers!

Comment: please use $match = instead of $match->message . may be you declare $match as array and try to store data in object manner so they give you this error  .

Comment: See [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper.

Comment: i don't think `first()->message;` is a valid syntax

Comment: can you please just execute "DB::table('logs')->get()" ? and check are you able to get data or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  conditions to check whether the record exists or not

```
$record = DB::table('logs')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->first();
if($record)
{
    $match->chatMessage = $record->message;
}
```

**Update**
for multiple record matching with same id you to use `get()`

```
$records = DB::table('logs')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->get(['id','message']); // Here you only select id,message from this model
if($records)
{
  foreach($records as $log){
    echo $log->message;
    // Add these message in one array for further use
  }
}
```

Comment: oh u really made me on the road! thanks! how about if not the `first` but all options of logs? Example: now i'm getting first message. How about all messages?

Comment: can u made a little example? @DsRaj

Answer (score -1):

You can use ->firstOrFail() and catch general exception somewhere. Additionally you don't have to use '=' in where statement because it is done by default.

Comment: firstOrFail() use with primary key only .

Comment: it can be used in any statement, it will just throw ModelNotFound exception if there is no result